# how can i get around this belongsToMany pivot error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have the following relationship for a belongsToMany relationship

```
Table:| users | forums  |forum_user (pivot table)
  | id        |  id     | id
  | name      |  name   | user_id
  | email     |         | forum_id
  |           |         |
```

and have defined the following relationships

```
pubic function forums() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Forum::class);
}
```

on the user model and

```
pubic function forums() {
   return $this->belongsToMany(Forum::class);
}
```

on the forum model

now when i try to do this

```
User::first()->forums()->get()
```

it returns the error

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Type of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::$ must be array (as in class 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model)
```

how can i get around this error

i'm currently using laravel 6 in my project

Comment: what does the `Forum` class extend?

Comment: It extends the Model class

Comment: The `Forum` model should have `public function users()`, and the `User` model should have `public function forums()`. I'm not sure if this was a copy-paste issue, but your code suggests you have the same function in both models.

Comment: It seems that the message you pasted `Type of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::$ must be array` is broken and missing important information. Please paste the real stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
User::first()->forums->get();
```

And maybe rewrite the relation on User model to:

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Forum::class, 'forum_user', 'user_id', 'forum_id');
```

Comment: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
Type of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot::$ must be array (as in class 
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model).  That's the error I get when I do that

Comment: Do you changed the relation on User model?

Answer (score 0):

On the forum model shouldnt relation reflect user?

```
 pubic function forums() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Forum::class);
 }
```

Shouldnt this be

```
 pubic function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
 }
```